# Returning a character from a string SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to write a SQL query to get all "a" in the string aabcaadfgaaa. I am using Oracle 11g database.

The result for this should be aaaaaaa

So, in case my input is Alaska the result should be aaa.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
Abhishek

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 6):

You have an odd requirement.  But you can do this using `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace(lower(col), '[^a]', '', 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use REGEXP_REPLACE:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE ('aabcaadfgaaa', '[^a]') FROM dual;
```

This is case sensitive, btw.